# How to count 2D List or List of Dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, 2d

I'm getting information from a text file, IP addresses and type for packets. I'm putting each occurrence of IP/Type into a list/dict? and then I want to find the count and if that IP/Type occur x amount of times, then I want to move that information to another list.

This is what I've tried so far.

List of Dicts:

```
data = [{'ip': '192.168', 'type': 'UDP'}, 
        {'ip': '192.173', 'type': 'TCP'}, 
        {'ip': '192.168', 'type': 'UDP'}]
```

or 2 dimensional List

```
data = [['192.168', 'UDP'], 
        ['192.173', 'TCP'], 
        ['192.168', 'UDP']]
```

I want to move 192.168, UDP to another list with the count because it showed up more than x times. I've tried a `Counter` but I can only get it to pass ip, not ip and type.

```
ipInfo = Counter(k['ip'] for k in data if k.get('ip'))
for info, count in ipInfo.most_common():
    print info, count
```

This only prints out `192.168, 2` not `192.168, UDP, 2`.

From my example, I want to be able to add `[192.168, UDP, 2]` or `{'ip': '192.168', 'type': 'UDP', 'count':2}` to another list.

Comment: Do you mean like Counter(k['ip'] for k in data.iteritems() if k.get('ip')) or Counter(data.iteritems()). Neither seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is a 2D list in your second form, you can use:

```
In [1]: data = [['192.168', 'UDP'], 
   ...:         ['192.173', 'TCP'], 
   ...:         ['192.168', 'UDP']] 

In [2]: c = Counter(tuple(r) for r in data)

In [3]: for info, count in c.most_common():
   ...:     print info, count

(u'192.168', u'UDP') 2
(u'192.173', u'TCP') 1
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks a lot. I'm still pretty new to python, so I'm not familiar with all these data structures, just learned about dictionaries recently.

Answer (score 1):

```
packetDict = {}

data = [['192.168', 'UDP'], 
        ['192.173', 'TCP'], 
        ['192.168', 'UDP']] 

for packetInfo in data:
  packetInfo = tuple(packetInfo)

  if packetInfo not in packetDict:
    packetDict[packetInfo] = 1
  else:
    packetDict[packetInfo] += 1

for pkt,count in packetDict.items():
  print(pkt,count)
```

**RESSULT**

```
('192.168', 'UDP') 2
('192.173', 'TCP') 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that would work for both a list-of-lists and a list-of-dicts:

```
from collections import Counter, Sequence
from pprint import pprint

def move_info(data):
    """ Copy info from data list into another list with an occurence count added.
        data can be a list of dicts or tuples.
    """
    if isinstance(data[0], dict):
        counter = Counter((dct['ip'], dct['type']) for dct in data1)
        result = [dict(ip=info[0], type=info[1], count=count) 
                            for info, count in sorted(counter.items())]
        return result
    elif isinstance(data[0], Sequence):
        counter = Counter(tuple(elem) for elem in data2)
        result = [list(info) + [count] for info, count in sorted(counter.items())]
        return result
    raise TypeError("Can't move info from a {}".format(type(data)))

# list of dicts
data1 = [{'ip': '192.168', 'type': 'UDP'},
         {'ip': '192.173', 'type': 'TCP'},
         {'ip': '192.168', 'type': 'UDP'}]

# list of lists
data2 = [['192.168', 'UDP'],
         ['192.173', 'TCP'],
         ['192.168', 'UDP']]

another_list = move_info(data1)
pprint(another_list)
print('')
another_list = move_info(data2)
pprint(another_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'count': 2, 'ip': '192.168', 'type': 'UDP'},
 {'count': 1, 'ip': '192.173', 'type': 'TCP'}]

[['192.168', 'UDP', 2], ['192.173', 'TCP', 1]]
```